# Points defining plane - starting step?

Tags: self-learning, vectors, cross-product

If the points $P, Q, R$, not all lying on the same straight line, have position vectors $a, b, c$ respectively, show that $(a \times b) + (b \times c) + (c \times a)$
is a vector perpendicular to the plane containing $P, Q, R$.

Comment: Most people on MSE like questions more when you explain a bit more. Where did you come across this question? Why do you care about the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The vectors $\vec{RP}=(a-c)$ and $\vec{RQ}=(b-c)$ are independent vectors in the plane orientation. Therefore their cross product will be normal to the plane.

$\begin{align}(a-c)\times (b-c) &=a\times b -c\times b-a \times c  + c\times c \\
&=a\times b +b\times c +c \times a + 0
\end{align}$